# Cast Button as String variable before getting/setting text

Tags: java, android, button, casting

How come this doesn't work:

```
 String btnText = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.my_Button).getText().toString();
```

But this does:

```
Button myButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.my_Button);
String btnText = myButton.getText().toString();
```

The getText() method can't resolve, but I'm not sure why when essentially these two line are the same.

Comment: You have to put one more closing small bracket after this : (R.id.my_Button) like - ((Button)findViewById(R.id.my_Button)) then you access Button getText() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cant find the method `getText()` because you are trying to call it from an Object type which was returned by the method `findViewById`

You forgot to add another layer of bracket to fully cast it as a Button to enable you to call the method `getText()`

```
String btnText = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.my_Button)).getText().toString();
```

For the second example you directly cast it and reference to an Button object therefore you can directly call `getText` method from the button object itself

Answer (score 2):

Forgot the brackets,

```
String btnText = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.my_Button)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

After converting find view reference to `Button` then you can access `getText()` method of `Button` :

After adding closing small bracket :

```
String btnText = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.my_Button)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: @LeonKowalski,Glad to help you.